# GET запрос возвращает промис. Как вернуть строку?

Tags: reactjs, яндекс-карты, axios, promise

Есть код для получения адреса по координатам:

```
export default function getAdress(list){
var $out = ''; // Тут будет записан адрес

// Метод работает только если есть список с координатами
if (list){
    // Ссылка для запроса
    var theUrl = `https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=${apikey}&geocode=${list[1]},${list[0]}&format=json`;
    
    // Функция запроса
    const get = async() => {
        var out = ''; // Эту перменную вернёт запрос

        await axios
            .get(theUrl)
            .then(
                (res) => {
                    // Запись адреса в переменную
                    out = res.data['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['name'];}
                )
            .catch(
                err => console.log(err)
            )

        return out;
    }


} else {
    console.log('Необходимо ввести координаты');
}

return $out;
}
```

Comment: По сути никак..

Comment: А чем вам промис не нравится?

Comment: @SwaD мне нужна именно строка или возможность получить строку

Comment: Ну так промис когда разрешится, будет вам строка. Похоже, что вам надо переделать код на работу с асинхронными функциями

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)